# Confused on when the basis of im A is the column space and when you have to do Gauss-Jordan

Tags: linear-algebra

I am confused on when the image of a matrix is directly the column space and when you have to do Gauss-Jordan and only pick the columns with a pivot in them.

Comment: The column space of a matrix _is_ its image. Those columns might not be linearly-independent, though, which you need for a basis.In general, figuring this out requires doing something akin to G-J.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column space of a matrix $A$ is a basis of the image when these columns are linearly independent, which means, by the *rank-nullity theorem*, that $\;\ker A=\{0\}$.